# Implementing Linux style file name wild cards on Windows 10 PowerShell

Tags: c++, regex, file-system, c++20

Implementing Linux style file name wild cards on Windows 10 PowerShell

While implementing an [objected oriented wc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/281253/portable-object-oriented-wc-linux-utility-word-count-c-20-counts-lines-wor) on Windows 10 in visual studio C++ I implemented a recursive file search with a weak attempt at pattern matching (regular expressions in file names). While unit testing it I discovered that it did not do a good job of file name matching. An example is that since the source code files of the `wc` program are a moving target, but I want to use those source files as test input for the `wc` program I created copies of the files with the file names ending in `.cpp.txt` and `.h.txt`. My `wc` program could not find these files separately, only as `.txt` files.

The code presented in this question fixes that bug in the program. This is only a stand alone test program. I haven't merged the code into the `wc` program yet.

This is my first attempt to use C++ regular expressions (std::regex).
One function in this code was contributed by another regular user here on Code Review, [Toby Speight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/75307/toby-speight). I copied that code and used it as the basis for another function, the one where I actually implement a regex.

### Questions:

- Are any of the Linux wild card characters missing?
- This should be pattern matching against file names only, does the regex in the code miss any legal characters in file names?
- Can the use of std::regex be improved here?
- Is there anything that isn't portable in this code?

### Requirements

This code requires gcc12 to compile, the ranges and views implementation are not available in gcc11.
This code will compile in Visual Studio 2022 when C++20 is selected.

```
/*
 * Testing Linux Shell file regular expressions on Windows 10. 
 * Need to be able to parse file specifications such as *.cpp.txt as well as
 * *.cpp or *.txt.
 */

#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

static const std::string BASE_SEARCH_DIR = "C:\\Users\\PaulC\\Documents\\ProjectsNfwsi\\StaticCodeEvalTools\\wconsteroids";
static const std::string questionMarkReplacement("[a-zA-Z0-9:$@#-_./]");
static const std::string starReplacement(questionMarkReplacement + "*");

namespace fsys = std::filesystem;

static std::string convertWildCards(std::string testInput)
{
    std::string regexString;
    try
    {
        std::regex qmark("\\?");
        regexString = std::regex_replace(testInput, qmark, questionMarkReplacement);
        std::regex asterisk("\\*");
        regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, asterisk, starReplacement);
    }
    catch (std::regex_error e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Regex Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return regexString;
}

struct SubDirNode
{
    fsys::path fileSpec;
    bool discovered = false;
    bool searchedFiles = false;

    SubDirNode(fsys::path path)
        : fileSpec{ std::move(path) }
    {
    }

    bool operator==(const SubDirNode& other) const
    {
        return fileSpec == other.fileSpec;
    }
    bool operator!=(const SubDirNode& other) const = default;
};

static bool SearchSubDirs = true;
static std::vector<SubDirNode> subDirectories;

/*
 * Search the current directory for sub directories.
 */
static auto findSubDirs(const SubDirNode& currentDir)
{
    // The code and comments in this function was contributed by @tobyspeight
    auto is_missing = [](const SubDirNode& branch) {
        return std::ranges::find(subDirectories, branch) == subDirectories.end();
    };

    auto subdirs = fsys::directory_iterator{ currentDir.fileSpec }
    | std::views::filter([](auto& f) { return f.is_directory(); })
        | std::views::transform([](auto& f)->SubDirNode { return f.path(); })
        | std::views::filter(is_missing);

    // TODO (C++23?) return std::vector(subdirs);
    auto newSubDirs = std::vector<SubDirNode>{};
    std::ranges::copy(subdirs, std::back_inserter(newSubDirs));
    return newSubDirs;
}

static bool discoverSubDirs()
{
    bool discoveredPhaseCompleted = true;
    std::vector<SubDirNode> newSubDirs;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < subDirectories.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!subDirectories[i].discovered)
        {
            std::vector<SubDirNode> tempNewDirs = findSubDirs(subDirectories[i]);
            if (tempNewDirs.size())
            {
                discoveredPhaseCompleted = false;
                newSubDirs.insert(newSubDirs.end(), tempNewDirs.begin(),
                    tempNewDirs.end());
            }
            subDirectories[i].discovered = true;
        }
    }

    // We are done searching the current level, append the new sub directories
    // to the old.
    subDirectories.insert(subDirectories.end(), newSubDirs.begin(), newSubDirs.end());
    return discoveredPhaseCompleted;
}

static std::vector<std::string> fileList;
static auto searchDirectoryForFilesByPattern(SubDirNode currentDir,
    std::string partialFileSpec)
{
    auto is_missing = [](const std::string& branch) {
        return std::ranges::find(fileList, branch) == fileList.end();
    };

    std::vector<std::string> newFiles = {};
    std::string patternString = convertWildCards(partialFileSpec);
    try
    {
        std::string dir = currentDir.fileSpec.string();
        std::regex pattern(patternString);
        auto is_type = [pattern](auto f) {
            return std::regex_search(f.path().string(), pattern);
        };

        auto files = fsys::directory_iterator{ currentDir.fileSpec }
            | std::views::filter([](auto& f) { return f.is_regular_file() ||
                f.is_character_file(); })
            | std::views::filter(is_type)
            | std::views::transform([](auto& f) { return f.path().string(); })
            | std::views::filter(is_missing);

            std::ranges::copy(files, std::back_inserter(newFiles));
    }
    catch (std::regex_error& re)
    {
        std::cerr << "Regex Error: " << re.what() << "\n";
        std::cerr << patternString << "\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return newFiles;
}

static void searchAllDirectoriesForFiles(std::string partialFileSpec)
{
    for (auto currentDir : subDirectories)
    {
        if (currentDir.discovered && !currentDir.searchedFiles)
        {
            std::vector<std::string> newFiles =
                searchDirectoryForFilesByPattern(currentDir, partialFileSpec);
            std::copy(newFiles.begin(), newFiles.end(), std::back_inserter(fileList));
            currentDir.searchedFiles = true;
        }
    }
}

static void discoverAllSubDirs()
{
    bool discoveryPhaseCompleted = false;
    while (!discoveryPhaseCompleted)
    {
        discoveryPhaseCompleted = discoverSubDirs();
    }
}

static std::vector<std::string> findAllFilesMatching(std::string partialFileSpec)
{
    fileList.clear();
    std::filesystem::path cwd = BASE_SEARCH_DIR;
    if (subDirectories.empty())
    {
        SubDirNode root(cwd);
        root.discovered = (SearchSubDirs) ? false : true;
        subDirectories.push_back(root);
    }

    discoverAllSubDirs();
    searchAllDirectoriesForFiles(partialFileSpec);
    
    return fileList;
}

static void testFindAllFilesMAtching(std::string partialFileSpec)
{
    std::cout << "Searching for files that match " << partialFileSpec << " found:\n";

    std::vector<std::string> matchingFiles = findAllFilesMatching(partialFileSpec);
    for (auto fileName : matchingFiles)
    {
        std::cout << "\t" << fileName << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    testFindAllFilesMAtching("CmdLineFileExtractor.cpp");
    testFindAllFilesMAtching("CmdLineFileExtractor.*");
    testFindAllFilesMAtching("Cmd*.cpp");
    testFindAllFilesMAtching("Cmd*.*");
    testFindAllFilesMAtching("Cmd*.cpp.txt");
    testFindAllFilesMAtching("Cmd*.*");
    testFindAllFilesMAtching("*.h");
    testFindAllFilesMAtching("*.cpp");
    testFindAllFilesMAtching("*.h.txt");
    testFindAllFilesMAtching("*.cpp.txt");
}
```

You will find some of this code in the current version of [wconsteroids](https://github.com/pacmaninbw/StaticCodeEvalTools/tree/PreCodeReview/wconsteroids).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` in a wildcard pattern matches *any character*, so we want `.` in place of `[a-zA-Z0-9:$@#-_./]`.  Actually, it will match a newline, so probably `(.|\n)` would be better.

`std::regex_error` should not be thrown unless we made a programming error; I'd replace the contents of that catch with an `assert(false)` and `abort()`.

The comment (written by me) `// TODO (C++23?) return std::vector(subdirs);` is inaccurate.  The correct and idiomatic C++23 will use `| std::ranges::to<std::vector>()`.

Comment: Since this is finding files I'm pretty sure newline is excluded. Can you have a newline in a file name?

Comment: Yes, of course.  On a POSIX system, any byte can be part of a filename except for `\0` and `/` (which is the directory separator).  (Certain filesystem types, notably VFAT, restrict characters in a filename, but most do not).